# Laravel HasManyThrough Keys

Tags: laravel, has-many-through

I have 3 models: User, Program, UserProgram.  UserProgram is an actual model of its own.

Here are how the models look in the database:

- users

  - id
- programs

  - id
- user_programs

  - user_id
  - program_id

I would like to have in my Program model:

```
function users() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User','App\UserProgram');
}
```

But this does not work.  How can I make this relationship work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasManyThrough` is not used for this purpose. You need a `many-to-many` relationship.

```
class Users {
  public function programs() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Program', 'user_programs', 'user_id', 'program_id');
  }
}
```

and

```
class Program {
  public function users() {
    return return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_programs', 'program_id', 'user_id');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful!