# Laravel eloquent, How to define relationships with versioning

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a product model with versioned data and I got a category model that can have one or many products. When I want to delete a category the code has to check if there are products related to the category. How to define the relation so that it goes to the `products_version` table to check if the `category_id` exists here before deleting it?

Here is my product model:

```
use Versionable, SoftDeletes;

protected $fillable = ['product_name', 'supplier', 'unit', 'pieces', 'desired_stock', 'current_stock', 'category_id', 'price'];

public $timestamps = true;

public $versioned = ['category_id', 'product_name', 'supplier','unit','desired_stock','current_stock','price','pieces', 'deleted_at'];

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

Versioning for products is working. I used the following code for it: https://github.com/ProAI/eloquent-versioning

My category model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

The code I used to check if there are products related to the category:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    // delete
    $category = Category::withCount('products')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();

    if ($category->products_count > 0) {
        Session::flash('message', 'Can not delete category');
    } else {
        $category->delete();
        // redirect
        Session::flash('success', 'Category deleted');
    }
    return Redirect::to('categories');
}
```

The error message I get:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'products.category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `categories`.*,
>   (select count(*) from `products` inner join `products_version` on
>   `products`.`id` = `products_version`.`ref_id` and
>   `products_version`.`version` = `products`.`latest_version` where
>   `categories`.`id` = `products`.`category_id` and
>   `products_version`.`deleted_at` is null) as `products_count` from
>   `categories` where `id` = 1 limit 1)

Comment: Could you show your migrations ? Cause it seems you don't have a category_id inside the product table.

Comment: @frogeyedman he have it inside `products_version` see `public $versioned = ['category_id', ....];`

Comment: Maybe he has it in the `$versioned` but not inside his table, as the error shows

Comment: In my products_version table, I do have a category_id comlumn.

Answer (score 1):

You may need something like `has many through` relationship

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product', 'App\ProductVersion');
}
```

So it will link `Category` to a `Product` through `ProductVersion` because `'category_id'` exists only in `ProductVersion`

Check [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) for more info

P.S. You may need to create `ProductVersion` model for `products_version` table

Comment: How would you define the relation? Because the package uses the ref_id and version to match the current version. So, the relation is based not on 1 field but 2, how can I access and/or define the "Product" entity with the `has many trough` syntax?

Comment: You can define keys see example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38287685/laravel-hasmanythrough-keys

Comment: Didn't work. The problem at the moment is, I get 2 inner joins in my query and that doesn't work because of the following error: Not unique table/alias: laravel

Comment: Direction is correct to use `hasManyThrough` but will need some custom, If I think of a solution I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
 $category = Category::withCount('products' => function($q) {
     $q->where('id', '=', $id);
 })->first();
```

Comment: This will not work because `category_id` doesn't exist on `products` table only on `products_version`